# Non-bijective wild endomorphisms of the complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

A ring endomorphism or automorphism of the complex numbers is said to be *wild* if it is different from the identity or complex conjugation. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412037/394668) it is said that “there are lots of [ring] endomorphisms [of $\mathbb{C}$] that are not automorphisms.”

If a wild endomorphism of the complex numbers exists, it must be non-continuous, for the only continuous endomorphisms are the identity and complex-conjugation. (Ring endomorphisms must be always $\mathbb{Q}$-linear and preserve the roots of the polynomial $x^2+1$. On the other hand, continuity gives us $\mathbb{R}$-linearity.)

My question is: how can we produce a non-bijective wild endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$? The only mention of such a thing I've been able to found on MSE or MO is the answer I linked above. On the other hand, the papers by [Kestelman](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kestelman51.pdf) and [Yale](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf) don't mention this.

[Here](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraist/2010/1384.htm) they explain a recipe to construct wild endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$. However, I don't understand the last step: “$g$ can be extended to a field endomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.” Specifically, I don't understand:

1. Why can we extend $g$ to a ring endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$? (I don't know much field theory so probably there is some result that is being used and that I am unaware of.)
2. How can we guarantee that $f$ will be a non-bijective wild endomorphism?

Comment: Pick any transcendence basis B of C over Q. Remove one element from B to obtain B'. The algebraic closure inside C of the subfield generated by B' is a subfield of C isomorphic to C but different from C.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I guess that would answer my question 2. Question 1 is left.

Comment: Question 1 is answered by a basic property of fields: you can extend morphisms. You should check any textbook!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Okay, I think Theorem 6.6 from [Milne](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) suffices. Thanks.